# Applications of Keisler measures

Tags: soft-question, model-theory

Keisler measures are finitely additive measures on the Boolean algebra of the definable subsets of some model.

They were introduced by [Keisler in 1987](https://doi.org/10.1016/0168-0072(87)90069-8) and did not receive much attention until [Hrushovski, Peterzil, and Pillay](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0607442) used them to solve an important conjecture.

Since then, Keiseler measure have become a mainstream topic in model theory.

Is there a more accessible result than the Hrushovski, Peterzil, Pillay theorem cited above that shows an application of Keisler measures?

Comment: I think it depends what you mean by "application" and "accessible". Invariant Keisler measures lead to the notions of amenability of a definable group or a first order theory. The concept of invariant measures is also simply a natural extension of the concept of invariant types. Keisler himself used measures to define the randomization of a first-order structure, which was later rephrased in the language of metric structures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One very nice application is the distal regularity lemma, which is a "Szemerédi regularity"-type statement for graphs definable in distal structures (the regularity is much more regular than what the Szemerédi Regularity Lemma gives us for arbitrary graphs).

The distal regularity lemma is due to Chernikov and Starchenko: [Regularity lemma for distal structures](https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.01482), generalizing previous work for semialgebraic graphs (i.e. graphs definable in the real field, a canonical example of a distal structure).

Shortly thereafter, Simon give a much quicker proof of the main result: [A Note on "Regularity lemma for distal structures"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.03955). Both proofs use Keisler measures in a crucial way. You might find Simon's note more "accessible" - or possibly too terse! Either way, the Chernikov-Starchenko paper contains a lot more background and motivation, so it's worth a read.

Comment: @Bonifacio The paper of Pierre Simon mentioned by Alex Kruckman is as accessible as it gets. But with a caveat. The definition of distality used by Simon is measure theoretic. At face value Simon only proves a result about Keisler measure. To obtain an *application* of Keisler measures you need prove the equivalence between the combinatorial definition of distality with the measure theoretic one. (If I am not mistaken, this is in PerreSimon's book.)

Comment: @PrimoPetri Good point - if you read the statements of the results (e.g. Theorem 2.2 in Simon), they look like statements *about* measures. To get the combinatorial applications to finite graphs, we take the generically stable measures mentioned in the statements to be the counting measures concentrated on finite subsets of a model.

Comment: Thank you both.